# Prevent users from accessing every wsdl element

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a SOAP web service that contains a bunch of different operations. I am trying to prevent all of them from being accessible to every user. I tried to accomplish this by editing the web.xml file security constraints.

Lets say my service has operation 1, 2, and 3. I have user1 and user2. I want user1 to be able to access 1, 2, and 3. user2 should only be able to access 3. I set up two security constraints with separate roles.

```
     <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>SOAP Service</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>user1</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>SOAP Service</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>user2</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

This works fine and allows both user1 and user2 to access everything exposed by the wsdl so then i tried to further restrict what user2 could do by changing the url-pattern.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>SOAP Service</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/3/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>user2</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

unfortunately this does not work. I was told this is because it is a soap request and all requests come in on the same url??? So i'm stuck now. What is the best way to allow certain users to only be able to access parts of a wsdl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to do a bunch of research because I didn't really understand enough about web services. In the end what i have is a web service that resides in a tomcat container, I use basic authentication configured in web.xml with users in tomcat-users.xml. The web.xml looks like

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>SOAP Service</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>serviceUsers</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>SOAP Service</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>otherUsers</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-role>
    <role-name>serviceUsers</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-role>
    <role-name>otherUsers</role-name>
</security-role>
```

This prevents anyone from accessing the service as a whole unless they have the role serviceUsers or otherUsers. What i wanted to do what block each operation though. To do this i had to edit my serviceEndpointImpl. What i added

```
@Resource
private WebServiceContext context;

if (context.isUserInRole("webServiceUsers")) { 
   //do whatever that user should be able to do or block them.
}
```

What this does is get the role of the user that connected to your service based on the tomcat-user.xml user name and password they used. Using this i was able to keep the authentication at the container level but still refuse users access to methods i did not want them to use.